# PHP get each line of textarea in jform

Tags: php

I am building a joomla 3 component. I have a text area set up in my xml document where the user can add additional JavaScripts (one per line). I then have some php which takes each line and adds the script to the head. Here is my php:

```
$BDjs = $this->params->get('bd-addjs');
$BDjsAr = explode("\n", $BDjs);
$BDjsAr = array_filter($BDjsAr, 'trim');
foreach ($BDjsAr as $line) {
    $line = str_replace('\n','',$line);
    $doc->addScript($line);
}
```

The PHP works fine but the rendered html has an extra line break in it as follows:

```
<script src="/dev/script1.js
" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/dev/script2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My question is how do I get rid on the line break after 'script1.js'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out by using preg_replace instead.

My final code is:

```
$BDjs = $this->params->get('bd-addjs');
$BDjsAr = explode("\n", $BDjs);
$BDjsAr = array_filter($BDjsAr, 'trim');
foreach ($BDjsAr as $line) {
    $line = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$line);
    $doc->addScript($line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `array_filter($BDjsAr, 'trim');` is useless...

as you already use foreach, just do:

```
$BDjs = $this->params->get('bd-addjs');
$BDjsAr = explode("\n", $BDjs);
foreach ($BDjsAr as $line) {
    $doc->addScript(trim($line));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I understand about your question:

- You are trusting the data coming from: `$this->params->get('bd-addjs');`
- You are expecting a single string of javascript filenames which are newline delimited AND potentially preceded/followed by whitespace characters.
- You want to isolate each filename based on the newline characters and individually include the files via `addScript()` after trimming the needless whitespace from each filename.

Your posted solution seems a bit indirect because you are exploding, then calling `preg_replace()` *n* times.

Worse, your `array_filter()` step is simply incorrect and has no effect on your strings.  [Here is proof](https://3v4l.org/kG4DG).

I recommend that you "**kill every bird with one stone**".  You can isolate the filenames, trim the whitespace characters (`[\s\t\r\n]`), and add a layer of validation like this:

[Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/FkIB4):

```
$test = "javascript1.js
 /dev/spacethenjs2.js

    doublenewline_tab_javascript3.js
/dev/javascript4.js
javascript5_trailingspaces.js    ";
var_export($test);
echo "\n---\nSee divided and trimmed output: ";
var_export(preg_match_all("~[/\w]+\.js\b~", $test, $matches) ? $matches[0] : 'no matches');
```

Output:

```
'javascript1.js
 /dev/spacethenjs2.js

    doublenewline_tab_javascript3.js
/dev/javascript4.js
javascript5_trailingspaces.js    '
---
See divided and trimmed output: array (
  0 => 'javascript1.js',
  1 => '/dev/spacethenjs2.js',
  2 => 'doublenewline_tab_javascript3.js',
  3 => '/dev/javascript4.js',
  4 => 'javascript5_trailingspaces.js',
)
```

To apply the above logic to your project, try this snippet:

```
if (preg_match_all("~[/\w]+\.js\b~", $BDjs, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $filename) {   // [0] contains all of the "fullstring" matches
        $doc->addScript($filename);
    }
}
```

If you don't follow what my regex pattern is doing, you can see [this regex101 demonstration with explanation](https://regex101.com/r/k1LyjT/2).

If your filenames vary more than my samples -- for instance if you have javascript filenames that have a querystring appended to them like `file.js?key=af32d12c94` then you can adjust the pattern to specifically handle such variance (`~[/\w]+\.js(?:\?key=\w+)?\b` or really loosen up the pattern (`~\S+\.js\S*`).

There are literally hundreds of patterns that can be created for different reasons.  You can write a few of your known filenames into the input box at regex101 and experiment with different patterns to see what will be best suited for your project.

Of course, if you aren't worried in the slightest about validation, you can use this alternative:

```
foreach (preg_split("~\s+~", $test, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $filename) {
    $doc->addScript($filename);
}
```

**Then again, if this string of text is coming from users, then you have EVERY REASONS TO WANT TO VALIDATE/SANITIZE IT TO WITHIN AN INCH OF ITS LIFE!!!**